# Must a ProgessDialog run in an AsyncTask or on a seperate Thread?

Tags: android-asynctask, progressdialog

I have two activities.  The second activity if for data collection from the user (he types in new data) and the first for showing graphs.  Once the user finish the second activity (by clicking back), I need to do calculations before the charts update on the MainActivity.  It is important that the calculations finish first before activity 2 is finished.  The code therefore runs in the onBackPressed method.

There seemed to be three options:

1) Use a thread that does the calculations and update the ProgressDialog with a seperate handler to watch for thread completion.  The handler receives a message once the thread is complete and then close the second activity.  Android Studio warns me that the handler needs to be static and warns me of memory leaks.  So this doesn't seem to be a safe approach.

2) Use an AsyncTask and wait until the AsyncTask is completed before closing activity two.  However, it appears meaningless to run a seperate thread or an AsyncTask for calculations that should run on the main thread simply to show a ProgressDialog.

3) Show the ProgressDialog on the main thread. However, this does not seem to be possible.

Could you please point this noob to the right method to show a ProgressDialog while sequentially executing calculations for which the user must wait (only a few seconds).

Thanks,

Jean

Answer (score 0):

Use the AsyncTask in Activity one there is no need to open second activity for load data and calculation you can do that in activity one and just use progress dialog in AsyncTask and close that dailog in postExecute method of Asynctask and Call that AsyncTask on OnCreate() method of Activity One.

Comment: Akhil, I've edited the question.  The second activity is necessary as the user provides data inputs in this activity.  It is not merely for loading data.

Comment: Call the first Activity on postExecute of AsyncTask of secondActivity and send data with Intent.

Comment: And perform your calculation on doinbackground method of Asynctask.